# Find values containing '03' in a particular table in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

What is the pay type for all the job codes that start with '03'?
name of the table- salary_range_by_job_classification.

CODE:

---

```
Select
job_code,
pay_type
FROM salary_range_by_job_classification
WHERE job_code= 03%
```

---

ERROR MESSAGE: near "%": syntax error.

DESIRED RESULT: job code values containing 03 in the ending
(But wildcards can be used only for string values.)

Comment: We love that you're here with us and we need to see an example of your code and an explanation of the problem so we can help you debug it.

Comment: Is `job_code` a number or a string?

Comment: If you have job codes starting with '03' then they are strings.

Comment: use `LIKE '03%'`, ref. https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/

Answer (score 1):

Use like in place of = .

```
Select
job_code,
pay_type
FROM salary_range_by_job_classification
WHERE job_code like '03%';
```

Comment: Your query is still lacking the quotes for the string literal: `like '03%';`.

Comment: Hey @Avantika Tyagi but the 'like' fn can be used only for string datatype and how is 03 considered a string?

Comment: You can also use like with number data type

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
WITH
salary_range_by_job_classification(job_code,pay_type) AS (
          SELECT 10100, 1
UNION ALL SELECT 10101, 6
UNION ALL SELECT 10102,12
UNION ALL SELECT 10103, 4
UNION ALL SELECT 10104, 1
UNION ALL SELECT 10105, 3
UNION ALL SELECT 10106, 6
UNION ALL SELECT 10201, 6
UNION ALL SELECT 10202,12
UNION ALL SELECT 10203, 4
UNION ALL SELECT 10204, 1
UNION ALL SELECT 10205, 3
UNION ALL SELECT 10206, 6
)
SELECT
  job_code
, pay_type
FROM salary_range_by_job_classification
-- you want an integer that ends in 03. calculation, not string op.
-- That is an integer whose modulo 100 is 3
WHERE job_code % 100 = 3;
-- out  job_code | pay_type 
-- out ----------+----------
-- out     10103 |        4
-- out     10203 |        4
```